# What does "Error" mean in Systems Manager Run Command (Document: AmazonCloudWatch-ManageAgent)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-ssm

I basically followed this web page.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-on-EC2-Instance-fleet.html

**Steps**

1. Launch an EC2 instance (Amazon Linux 2) with an IAM role (Permissions: CloudWatchAgentServerRole, AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore).
2. See "Download the CloudWatch agent package" section in the documentation and run "AWS-ConfigureAWSPackage".
3. Go to Systems Manager Parameter Store and create a parameter.

Name: AmazonCloudWatch-linux
Parameter: see below

```
{
  "metrics": {
    "append_dimensions": {
      "ImageId": "${!aws:ImageId}",
      "InstanceId": "${!aws:InstanceId}",
      "InstanceType": "${!aws:InstanceType}"
    },
    "metrics_collected": {
      "mem": {
        "measurement": [
          "mem_used_percent"
        ],
        "metrics_collection_interval": 60
      }
    }
  }
}
```

4. See "Start the CloudWatch agent" section in the documentation and run "AmazonCloudWatch-ManageAgent". I input "AmazonCloudWatch-linux" to the "Optional Configuration Location" box.
5. To check the status of CloudWatch Agent, I run `sudo /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -m ec2 -a status`, and this below is returned. This means CloudWatch Agent is running successfully.

```
{
  "status": "running",
  "starttime": "2022-07-20T15:06:12+0000",
  "configstatus": "configured",
  "cwoc_status": "running",
  "cwoc_starttime": "2022-07-20T15:06:11+0000",
  "cwoc_configstatus": "configured",
  "version": "1.247353.0b251941"
}
```

6. I also go to CloudWatch Metrics and confirm I get a new metric.
7. However, the execution history of "AmazonCloudWatch-ManageAgent" (Step 4) has some messages in "Error".

```
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/cwagent-otel-collector.service to /etc/systemd/system/cwagent-otel-collector.service.
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart cwagent-otel-collector.service
2022/07/20 15:06:12 D! [EC2] Found active network interface
2022/07/20 15:06:12 Reading json config file path: /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d/ssm_AmazonCloudWatch-linux.tmp ...
2022/07/20 15:06:12 I! Valid Json input schema.
2022/07/20 15:06:12 D! [EC2] Found active network interface
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.service to /etc/systemd/system/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.service.
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart amazon-cloudwatch-agent.service
```

[image: Run Command Execution History]

8. I also check "Output" of the execution history. In my understanding, this does not show any issues.

```
****** processing cwagent-otel-collector ******
Successfully fetched the config and saved in /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/cwagent-otel-collector/etc/cwagent-otel-collector.d/default.tmp
cwagent-otel-collector config has been successfully fetched.
cwagent-otel-collector has already been stopped

****** processing amazon-cloudwatch-agent ******
/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config-downloader --output-dir /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d --download-source ssm:AmazonCloudWatch-linux --mode ec2 --config /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/common-config.toml --multi-config default
I! Trying to detect region from ec2
Region: ap-northeast-1
credsConfig: map[]
Successfully fetched the config and saved in /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d/ssm_AmazonCloudWatch-linux.tmp
Start configuration validation...
/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config-translator --input /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json --input-dir /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d --output /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.toml --mode ec2 --config /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/common-config.toml --multi-config default
I! Detecting run_as_user...
I! Trying to detect region from ec2
No csm configuration found.
No log configuration found.
Configuration validation first phase succeeded
/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent -schematest -config /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.toml
Configuration validation second phase succeeded
Configuration validation succeeded
amazon-cloudwatch-agent has already been stopped
```

**Question**

Even though there is no problem at Step 5, 6 and 8, why is there a message in Error at Step 7?

Comment: Where is the error message..? don't see any

Comment: @Riz Hi, I added a screenshot to clarify what I mean by "Error".

Comment: So is the agent not streaming the logs?

Comment: @Paolo it is streaming the logs (I meant this in Step 6). That's why I'm confused.

Comment: Are there any errors in the cloudwatch logs on the server?